# If I use Heroku scheduler, do I still need delayed job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, delayed-job

I'm a little confused about this. I have a couple of tasks that I would like to run asynchronously, for example my inventory sync integration. For this I have implemented delayed job, but I realize that I need to run rake jobs:work on Heroku for this. I can use the Heroku scheduler to run this rake task every 10 minutes. My question is; if I create rake tasks to run i.e. my inventory sync method, do I still need delayed job? My understanding is that heroku scheduler kicks off 'one off dynos'.

Instead of using delayed job, could I not just kick off the sync method directly since a separate dyno is used anyway? What is the added value of delayed job here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku's Scheduler replaces what cron would handle on a typical server. Delayed Job or Sidekiq are for processing jobs asynchronously from your app, not a timed schedule.

The reason you use a worker & run these jobs on the back-end is so that your server can return a response as soon as is possible rather than making the user wait for some potentially unnecessarily long running process to finish (lots of queries, outbound e-mail, external API requests, etc.).

Ex, scheduler can run analytics or updates from a script every hour or day, but delayed job can not.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, if my inventory sync would be initiated by a user, it would be useful to use delayed job (and have the heroku scheduler run the process). If it is not initiated by a user but just runs on a (heroku) schedule, I do not need delayed job?

Comment: I would suggest that anything that should be run at a specific time daily or hourly be triggered by Heroku Scheduler, and in Rails you can use a rake task to do that, ex: `rake inventory:sync` if you have an inventory namespace and a task named sync. In that rake task, you can do the processing, or (what I would do) trigger a worker/job to do it in the background.